# AutoHotKey to type"powercfg batteryreport" in CMD

Tags: cmd, autohotkey

This  might be a tricky thing.

I want to use something Ctrl + b  to automatically open CMD and type "powercfg batteryreport" and then should for 4 seconds. so that I can see my laptop battery usage.

Comment: You can try: 

``run, %comspec% /k powercfg /batteryreport, , max``

I am on Mac and cannot test it locally.

Answer (score 0):

```
; Ctrl + b
^b::    
    ; The %ComSpec% command starts a new instance of the command interpreter (CMD.exe)
    ; /k means: keep (do not close) this session after execution. The console window will remain open, even if the task has been finished already.
    Run, %ComSpec% /k powercfg batteryreport
    ; ahk_exe is used to identify a window belonging to the process with the given name
    WinWait, ahk_exe cmd.exe ; wait until the specified window exists
    Sleep, 4000 ; wait 4 seconds
    ; ControlSend sends simulated keystrokes to a window or control 
    ControlSend,, exit{Enter}, ahk_exe cmd.exe ; close cmd window
    ; open the output file (Win7):
    Run %A_WinDir%\system32\battery-report.html
return
```

For more details see [Run](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#Remarks), [ahk_exe](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_exe), [WinWait](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm), [ControlSend](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm) in the documentation.

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21586914)

Comment: can you make it like this that the window should close as my task finishes? After waiting for 4 seconds it should type another command to open the output file i.e. created by "Run, %ComSpec% /k powercfg batteryreport". the file name is battery-report.html  and after that the cmd window closes